# Full-text search on in-memory optimize table sql server

Tags: sql-server

How can I do a full-text search like containstable or freetexttable on in-memory optimize table SQL Server?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] before posting a question

Comment: you can vote add this feature here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/41951560-create-fulltext-index-for-in-memory-oltp

Answer (score 1):

Fulltext indexes are not supported for memory-optimized tables.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/transact-sql-constructs-not-supported-by-in-memory-oltp

Comment: So how can we optimize searching through in-memory tables?